# Why i can't add .NetCore2.0 project referance to NetStandart2.0 project?

Tags: reference, .net-core, .net-standard

It gives me error :

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Project '..' targets 'netcoreapp2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.    ..Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   1601
>   "

Comment: The question states a fact, a .NETStandard project can only reference .NETStandard libraries.  Required to stay standard.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core implements the .NET Standard.

If you were to add a dependency from a .NET Standard library to a .NET Core assembly then the resulting assembly would no longer work on other platforms that implement .NET Standard.